# Got an error while using react-native-maps try to run in android emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, react-native

I am working on a sample project, in that I used a `react-native-maps` module it works great in IOS but it throws an error in android `emulator.i` Installed Google Repositories, play-services using Android SDK `manager.the` issue is

> Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0.

Below is the screenshot for above mentioned error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewMwG.png)

Please,give me suggestions how to resolve this error.Any valuable suggestions are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this issue posted in github .It may be helpful.

[react-native-maps issues](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/issues/998)